# Php generated wrong format url file path after upload to server

Tags: php, json, image, url

Below is the code for me to generate a unique file Url of each image uploaded and store it to database.

```
    //create unique image file name based on micro time and date
    $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
    $id = $now->format('YmdHisu');

    // Path to move uploaded files
    $target_path = "uploads";
    //the file name
    $path = "$target_path/$id.jpeg";

    // getting server ip address
    $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

    // final file url that is being uploaded
    $file_upload_url = 'http://'. $server_ip . '/' . 'abc' . '/' .$path;
```

What I expect for this code should generate the url in `json_encode` as below:

```
http://111.111.11.1/abc/uploads/20170226041004809200.jpeg
```

But now the problem is it generate the Url but in `json_encode` result is  like below

```
http:\/\/111.111.11.1\/abc\/uploads\/20170226041004809200.jpeg
```

What I tried so far,

```
$file_upload_url = 'http:'. $server_ip  . 'abc'  .$path;
```

But it not what I want,it become this

```
http:111.111.11.1.1abcuploads\/20170226041515563600.jpeg
```

Can somebody have any idea how to solve this?Or have a better suggestion?

Comment: are you uploading the image on same server that your current web-app/website deployed

Comment: yup..same server..and also in the same folder

Comment: I want to get rid of the "\" inside the URL.I try `str_replace` but didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_replace` to replace the `\`

```
<?php
   $file_upload_url = "http:\/\/111.111.11.1\/abc\/uploads\/20170226041004809200.jpeg";
   $upload_path = str_replace('\\','',$file_upload_url);
   echo $upload_path;
?>
```

Comment: so i at this 2 link of code after $file_upload_url ?am i right?

Comment: cant replace "\" cause it make my " not running

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on same server then why don't you try to upload file with code snippet-

```
 $file_upload_url = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]). '/abc' . '/' .$path;
// you can manage url by -
$base_url  = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$base_url.=$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$base_url.='/abc/'.$path
// now print your url-
echo $base_url;
```

Comment: please adjust your path by printing `realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])`, hope this helpful to you. Please let me know whether it works for you or not

Comment: I just try your solution sir `C:\\wamp64\\www\/abc\/uploads\/20170226051524150800.jpeg` the "\" in the URL still exist.and I need `http` url cause I need to get the url later in android

Comment: is uploaded,I appear in uploads folder..but the Url i need `http` sir

Comment: http:\/\/10.0.0.0\\abc\\v1\/\/abc\/uploads\/20170226052839045100.jpeg I become like this,and the 10.0.0.0 is the android local Ip.still didnt work sir

Comment: `$file_upload_url ` never used?

Comment: sir it didnt work now the URL is `http:\/\/10.0.2.2C:\\wamp64\\www\/abc\/uploads\/20170226054004883300.jpeg`

Comment: are you there @ken

Comment: yup..i here but still the same `http:\/\/10.0.0.0\/abc\/uploads\/20170226055102072300.jpeg`

Comment: `http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/abc\/uploads\/20170226061153370400.jpeg` the path now is this bro..I think I should remove the backslashes

Comment: if correct , please accept as correct answer and upvote to if possible ...